# Perl - Can't load Expat.xs.dll

Tags: perl, dll, cgi, xml-rpc, bugzilla

Dear all I try to get XML RPC running on Bugzilla. I installed all perl modules what has been described by mozilla. but when I like to access the perl cgi script http://localhost:8010/xmlrpc.cgi I get the following error.

*Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/XML/Parser/Expat/Expat.xs.dll' for module XML::Parser::Expat: load_file:the requested modul get not found at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.*

I verified the mentioned dll file  is existign at the place C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/XML/Parser/Expat/Expat.xs.dll. Here I assume the dll may require other dependent dll and other perl modules. Apache  log file does not show me any additional information.

Any hint what I can do?

I am using

- Strawberry Perl v5.22.1 (64bit)
- Bugzilla v4.4.11
- Apache v2.4
- Windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened a bug on the mozilla page for bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1240367

The support answered me that strawberry is not supported for bugzilla v4.4 however I could solve the problem by copying the C:\Strawberry\c\bin\libexpat-1__.dll to C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\auto\XML\Parser\Expat\libexpat-1__.dll (same directory as Expat.xs.dll is located). After that the XML Parser stuff and Expat.xs.dll could be executed properly.

May be it helps for others. Regards

Answer (score 2):

I think the right answer should be:
add the folders

```
C:\{PerlFolder}\c\bin\ 
C:\{PerlFolder}\perl\bin
```

to the path under environment variables.
where {PerlFolder} in your case is "Strawberry"

Answer (score -1):

same pb, solved by adding perl\bin in path